# Role-Based Authorization in blazor web assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

In a blazor web assembly, for a authenticated user, I want to restrict any access to the app if they do not belong to certain AD group with certain role. Lets say I have a group with role 'xyz' configured in Azure portal. My app should only allow access to those users. For others, it should show a 401. I am trying to do it at a global level, and not individually to a controller or view. I have this set up in startup.cs in ConfigureServices :

```
     var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .RequireRole("xyz")
                        .Build();

        services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy)));
```

This is not effective. I am expecting a 401 response or something along those lines. Please advice on what I am missing or something that helps me understand this a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate user with specified app role we need to add users as admin or viewer at ***AZURE AD> SELECT ROLE(viwer,admin)*** for both client and server app for app roles.

For example in `startup.cs`  we can add something like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType =
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
        },
        options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

***For complete setup*** please refer this [***BLOG***](https://code-maze.com/using-app-roles-with-azure-active-directory-and-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps/) & for returning `401 response` you can refer this [***Blog***](https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-role-based-authorization/) as well.